# How to convert PDF to HTML with exact look and feel in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I am a beginner in Symfony2.
I want to convert a PDF file in to HTML keeping the same look and feel

Comment: Do you have any code that you've made a start on?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I tried some libraries, exclusively for Linux, but here is my intermediate conclusion.

[PDFtoHTML](http://pdftohtml.sourceforge.net/) is too old and doesn't take in consideration all new PDF Specifications, for example PDF 1.7 (mainly because it use xpdf 2.02, while xpdf is already in his 3 version)

Instead of PDFTOHTML I found [Poppler](http://poppler.freedesktop.org/) that continues the PDFtoHTML development plus some new utils very useful. Actually, in Open Source Poppler was the one who rendered better my complex PDF. Here one almost equal I've to use.

Finally, [here](http://www.ren21.net/Portals/97/documents/GSR/GSR2011_Master18.pdf) is it what I'm gonna use. ImageMagick + Poppler. I will convert my PDF to images and use the XML output from Poppler of PDFtoHTML to add a new layer on my image.

Comment: Thank you for your reply It would be really appreciable if you can  guide us  for its (poppler) installations this is because I had tried to install poppler through the steps provided in link but display bellow error 

` /poppler1/poppler-0.32.0$ make
    make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.`